# How to make result a proper sentence?

Tags: python

I made a really simple program that requests an input and puts a comma or question mark at the end. If the sentence starts with why, how, etc, the program adds an question mark.

But how can I make the last comma a period, so that I can make a proper sentence?

The code:

```
def sentence_maker(phrase):
    x = ("Why", "What", "Who", "How")
    sentence = phrase.capitalize()
    if sentence.startswith(x):
        return "{}?\n".format(sentence)
    else:
        return "{},".format(sentence)

results = []
while True:
    y = input("Say something: ")
    if y=="end":
        break
    else:
        results.append(sentence_maker(y))

print(" " .join(results))
```

The idea is to make something that work like this:
input: 
    `say something: hello
    say something: how are you 
    say something: i'am good 
    say something: thank you`

output:

```
 Hello, How are you?
I'am good, Thank you.
```

Comment: Couldn’t you just replace the comma with a period in the string formatting?

Comment: Maybe the idea is that there can be several subsentences? The question would be much better with a couple of examples of desired behaviour.

Comment: I forgot to add: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this could be to edit the last element after registering that the input is "end".

```
while True:
    y = input("Say something: ")
    if y=="end":
        results[-1] = results[-1][:-1] + "."
        break
    else:
        results.append(sentence_maker(y))
```

**Test Output:**

```
Say something: Why
Say something: the
Say something: quick
Say something: brown
Say something: fox
Say something: jumps
Say something: end
Why?
 The, Quick, Brown, Fox, Jumps.
```

Comment: You'll need to add a check if the last character was a comma though, as now it will also replace a question mark.